# Распарсить XML

Tags: xml, qt, c++, синтаксический-анализ

Добрый день. Помогите, пожалуйста? средствами `Qt` или других `C++` библиотек распарсить `XML` ответ сервера в таком виде.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response list="true">
<count>0</count>
</response>
```

Из дерева нужно получить `count`. Сам `XML` может меняться, но `count` всегда будет первым элементом.
Заранее спасибо! :)

Comment: Используйте [`QXmlQuery.`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qxmlquery.html)

Answer (score 1):

`QDomDocument`

- [QDomDocument Class Reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdomdocument.html)
- [Описание класса QDomDocument](http://doc.crossplatform.ru/qt/4.3.2/qdomdocument.html)